# Error when running deploy assets script for cdk

Tags: aws-cdk, aws-code-deploy

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9syY5.png)I'm currently trying to deploy assets to Gamma and I'm getting an error stating failed to run 'bootstrap' on package when running bb deploy:assets  . Has anyone had this issue?

I tried these steps:

kinit -f && mwinit -o

toolbox install batscli
bats cache -c && bats cache -u

bws clean
bws sync
bbb

ada credentials update --provider=conduit --role=IibsAdminAccess-DO-NOT-DELETE --once --account= 12345678

bb deploy:assets Ada1pmPossumAttributionKestrelAggregationEMR-Gamma